# How to use a solution from a model to solve another one

Tags: cplex, opl

I'm solving an optimization problem in which I need the result from one model to be used as a restriction in another model.
I'm using CPLEX with OPL language without any addon.

I tried to save the values from one model into an Excel file and reading those into the next model but since I'm going to work with huge data files that won't be enough to do the job.

Theoretically I want to sequentially compile the two models, in which the data of the first model needs to be saved in memory and used to solve the other one. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that through flow control and use of a "main" block.
I wrote an example at

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=471cc451-9dc2-44d8-a0e9-5f146fb14765&ps=25

and the information transfer is in

```
data2.maxOfx=opl1.y.solutionValue; // transfer solution of model1 to input for model2
```

Comment: One small question Alex. Will this work while using OPL language correct? No need for an addon with another programming language right?

Comment: Right, opl only is enough